# Solved Lotus domino 550 5.1.1 Error: user unknown on a newly created database

Tags: email, email-server, ibm-domino

Good Morning

i'm having some trouble with a newly created Domino Database. When i try to send an email from an external address, i get "550 5.1.1 Error: user unknown" error

i've created the database using the registration tool inside Domino Administrator:

in the tab "People & Groups", on the "Tools" column, i selected "people > register" and added all the information i usually add to create a new entry, with an email address. I did certify the email database with the correct id from my company.

Then i proceeded to register it and typed in the server console

load updall names.nsf 
tell adminp process all

after that, the database can send and receive emails from internal databases, and send emails otside too.

Any suggestion?

Thanks for all your time and help in advance

Enrico

[Edit] The problem wasn't caused by the server.

Comment: Please describe what you have done: Creating a Domino Database does not create any entry that makes that database routable... You need a mailin document or even a mail user in order to be able to send an email to a database... AND: user onknown may come from a spam filter / firewall that is in front of your Domino and needs to know the new addresses as well before routing is possible...

Comment: Thaks for your suggestion, i've added some details i hope can be useful

Answer (score 0):

The error is normal as your domino inst authoritative for that external domain.

If your goal is to setup something like a gmail account for a domino's user, then you have to add the gmail account information into the client.

Comment: I'm sorry, i think i haven't understood your answer. i guess, but please correct me if i'm wrong, that i have to use a certifier id for the external domain, which i do.

Comment: @EnricoDrusiani Please update your question, as is, we can't know if it's like a hotmail or gmail, or from a outside address from another domino directory like you are telling me